# Como aplicar mismo js a un div pero que hagan diferente implementacion - Estrellas de Calificacion

Tags: javascript, flask

Quiero hacer un Calificador de Estrellas en cada una de las tarjetas con una puntuacion diferente en cada una de ellas.
El problema es que a todas se le asocia la misma puntuacion.

Este codigo lo que hace es que se asigna el valor film['rating'] para que el js se ejecute pero el valor para las diferente tarjetas es el mismo.
Sabrian si puedo hacer que las estrellas de calificación que se vean en cada tarjeta sean diferentes e independientes del resto o si saben otra forma de implementar un calificador de estrellas independiente me gustaria saber su opinion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**stars.js**

```
function ready(fn) {
    if(document.readyState != 'loading') {
      fn();
    } else {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
  }
  
  var selectedRating = parseInt(document.getElementById('rating-stars').getAttribute("value"));
  
  ready(function(){
  
    function addClass(el, className) {
      if(typeof el.length == "number") {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(el, function(e,i){ addClass(e, className) });
        return;
      }
      if (el.classList)
        el.classList.add(className);
      else
        el.className += ' ' + className;    
    }
    function removeClass(el, className) {
      if(typeof el.length == "number") {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(el, function(e,i){ removeClass(e, className) });
        return;
      }
      if (el.classList)
        el.classList.remove(className);
      else if(el.className)
        el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
    }
  
    var stars = document.querySelectorAll(".rating-stars a");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(stars, function(el, i){
      el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt){
        removeClass(stars, "selected");
        // For each star up to the highlighted one, add "hover"
        var to = parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute("data-rating"));
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(stars, function(star, i) {
          if(parseInt(star.getAttribute("data-rating")) <= to) {
            addClass(star, "hover");
          }
        });
      });
      el.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt){
        removeClass(evt.target, "hover");
      });
      el.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
        selectedRating = parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute("data-rating"));
        removeClass(stars, "selected");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(stars, function(star, i) {
          if(parseInt(star.getAttribute("data-rating")) <= selectedRating) {
            addClass(star, "selected");
          }
        });      
        evt.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    document.querySelector(".rating-stars").addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt){
      // When the cursor leaves the whole rating star area, remove the "hover" class and apply 
      // the "selected" class to the number of stars selected.
      removeClass(stars, "hover");
      if(selectedRating) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(stars, function(star, i) {
          if(parseInt(star.getAttribute("data-rating")) <= selectedRating) {
            addClass(star, "selected");
          }
        });      
      }
    });
    
  });
```

**stars.css**

```
.rating-stars a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("/static/img/rating-star.png");
    outline: none;
  }
  .rating-stars a.hover {
    background-image: url("/static/img/rating-star-yellow.png");
  }
  .rating-stars a.selected {
    background-image: url("/static/img/rating-star-yellow.png");
  }
```

**content_category.html**

```
  {% for film in film_data %}
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 576px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md">
        <img class="card-img" src="/static/img/film/{{ film['image_name'] }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title: {{ film['title'] }}</h5>
          <h6 class="card-title">Year: {{ film['year'] }}</h6>
          <div id="rating-stars" class="rating-stars" value="{{ film['rating'] }}">
            <a href="" data-rating="1"></a>
            <a href="" data-rating="2"></a>
            <a href="" data-rating="3"></a>
            <a href="" data-rating="4"></a>
            <a href="" data-rating="5"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: No puedes darle el mismo atributo `id` a tus elementos. Esto: `id="rating-stars"` debe ser único por cada elemento. Podrías usar algún valor específico, como por ejemplo: `id="{{ film['id'] }}"` si acaso tus datos incluyen un campo `id`. Esto con la idea de implementar un elemento `div` único y diferente de los demás. Empieza por ajustar eso. Saludos

Comment: Yo no termino de entender la duda

Comment: A tu pregunta le faltan muchos detalla, adjuntas código pero lo que intentas con ese código. Tu código tiene un montón de errores, hay estructuras condicionales que no abren y cierran con llaves ({}). Tiene una grave confusión con los `id` y `class`. En el HTML defines `rating-stars` como `id` y en CSS usas un punto (los id usan #). Finalmente en JavaScript usas `getElementById()` por lo tanto va ser único...